# What does DON stand for?

Tags: oracles, chainlink, dao

to give a bit of context, I'm trying to follow a conversation about possible ways to do off chain voting for a DAO, and the acronym "DON" keeps being mentioned.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DON stands for "Decentralized Oracle Network", and is often referred to in the [Chainlink Whitepaper V2](https://chain.link/whitepaper).

It is a network of oracles that are connected to give data in a decentralized manner and do external execution.